# Error getting value from 'IsCurrentTimestampSelectStringCallable' on 'NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect'

Tags: c#, sqlite, nhibernate, json.net

I am at dead end now :(
I am trying to serialize my object by NewtonSoft.Json

```
   string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(doc);
```

and getting such exception:

```
   Error getting value from 'IsCurrentTimestampSelectStringCallable' on 'NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect'.
```

with inner exception:

```
  Database does not known how to define a current timestamp function
```

I am using in project such libraries - nhibernate, newtonsoft.json.net and sqlite(http://system.data.sqlite.org/) - all of them are for .net 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem that json.net was trying to deserialize lazy object.

Comment: Thanx for stating the problem, what is the solution though